# Find the Scalar Tangential component of acceleration

Tags: calculus, vectors, chain-rule, scalar-fields

Question :

r(t) = **3sint i + 2 cost j - sin2t** k at **t=π/2**

Find Scalar Tangential component of acceleration.

Answer:

Given, r(t) = 3sint i + 2 cost j - sin2t k

Velocity,V = r'(t) = 3cost i - 2sint j - 2cos2t k

V(t=π/2) = -2j + 2k

Acceleration, a = r''(t)  = -3sint i - 2cost j + 4sin2t k

a (t=π/2) = -3i

The equation of Scalar Tangential component of acceleration, aT is

```
      aT =( v . a ) / | v |
     
           = (-2j + 2k) . ( -3i ) / root (8)
           = 0
```

Here I am getting (-2j + 2k) . ( -3i ) =0
Is this correct?

Therefore the Scalar Tangential component of acceleration, aT is 0

Is there any mistake in my calculation? I don't have the real answer to this question?  Is my answer correct?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any mistake in my calculation?

No.

> I don't have the real answer to this question? Is my answer correct?

Yes.